# Convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}-n\sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})}{n}$.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Does the sum in the title converge? $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}-n\sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})}{n} = \sum (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$), so one can use the integral criteria, which says the sum converges iff the integral $I = \int_1^{\infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}))$ converges. Heuristically, $I$ is the area between $y=x$ and $y=\sin(x)$ on the interval $(0;1)$ and this area is evidently (heuristically) finite.

But is there some more analytical (= rigorous, classical) approach? Some convergent series to compare it with, for example? I'm just trying to find some solution (or find out whether there exists one) which would be accessible to an average student after the basic calculus course.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ at $0$ of order $3$ for example does it.

Comment: Sure, Taylors definitely do, thank you! But this is (for me) still a 'brute force'..I'm looking for a yet smoother way..

Answer (score 2):

It is not really clear to me what you are after, but maybe something like this, which is close to Maclaurin, but a pure estimate?

Integrating (from $0$ to $x$) the well-known inequality
$$
\sin x\leq x,\quad x\geq 0.
$$
we get
$$
1-\cos x=\int_0^x\sin t\,dt\leq \int_0^x t\,dt= x^2/2.
$$
Repeating,
$$
x-\sin x=\int_0^x 1-\cos t\,dt\leq \int_0^x t^2/2\,dt= x^3/6.
$$
Thus, for $x\geq 0$, we have
$$
0\leq x-\sin x\leq x^3/6.
$$
With $x=1/\sqrt{n}$,
$$
0\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{6n^{3/2}}
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{6n^{3/2}}
$$
converges, so do
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Very nice.. I'm just trying to find some solution (or find out whether there exists one) which would be accessible to an average student after the basic calculus course.

Comment: Then I think this comes pretty close, at least. Perhaps you should update your question with that extra information, since it might be useful for others who think of answering your question.